# Psensors not displaying AMD radeon card's temperature. Solutions?

Tags: 16.04, radeon, overheating, temperature, amd-graphics

I am having some overheating issues in my laptop running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, so I just wanted to monitor my gpu temperature using psensor. After properly installing the dependencies and psensor itself when I run

```
sensors
```

in terminal, what I get is this -

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +46.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp2:         +0.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp3:        +37.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp4:        +42.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp5:        +24.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp6:       +127.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)

radeon-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:            N/A  (crit = +120.0°C, hyst = +90.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +47.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:         +46.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:         +44.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
```

As you can see my gpu temperature is not being displayed. Any idea why?

And also, temp6 is showing 127 C which is strange because nothing in my PC is even close to that hot.

PC Configuration:
HP ProBook 4540s
Intel Corei5-3230M 2.60 GHz
4GB RAM
AMD Radeon HD 7650

Comment: temp 6 can be ignored there are often sensors that aren't connected by the manufacturer and will give odd readings like +127 or -127 ... its a normal thing My ASUS board on my desktop has one reading like that .. and my Asus board in my server shows `temp3:       -128.0°C  (low  =  -1.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  sensor = disabled` as for you issue ... I'm looking into it to see if I can come up with a resolution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your laptop probably has 2 GPUs (one integrated and one discrete).

When you run `sensors` the discrete GPU is off therefore there is no temperature reading available.

You have to first activate your discrete (Radeon) card and then run `sensors` again.

One simple way I have found is this:

1. You install mesa-utils (`apt install mesa-utils`)
2. Then run glxgears with your discrete graphics card turned on like this: `DRI_PRIME=1 glxgears`
3. While glxgears is running open a new terminal window and run `sensors` again. You should see a temperature reading from your Radeon card now.

The above method worked for my Radeon card.

I think the issue is due to Linux kernel having DPM (Dynamic Power Management) turned on for Radeon cards. This makes sense, as you wouldn't want your discrete GPU to be turned on all the time and consuming power.